# One sheet responding to Cells.Clear/writing significantly slower than others

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that imports data from about 100 other workbooks into 3 sheets in ThisWorkbook.

When the sub runs, it clears all data previously loaded in the destination sheets. I've always had Cells.Clear be a quick operation, but I've noticed that one of the worksheets in particular drags quite a bit when I step through. This is the case even when that sheet is completely blank prior to running Cells.Clear.

Further, I've also noticed that writing to that sheet, and only that sheet, is now dragging as well.

I've tried:

- Manually clearing everything from the offending sheet using the Ribbon
- Checking for hidden data via Go To Last Cell (Last Cell is A1)
- Running VBA code to clear formats on this sheet

Recent changes:

- Things became pronounced yesterday after I broke one giant sub into several. Perhaps I'm not doing something right with how I declare variables, etc.?
- I decided to move to Cells.Clear and just re-establish the headers on the import pages by code (rather than clearing A3:Z1000000 each time)

My best idea at this point is to try deleting the sheet and making a new one, but I'd like to learn what may be causing this and if there are ways to avoid this by coding differently.

The full module has 406 lines of code so I will try to post just the relevant code. If you want to see more, just ask.

The offending sheet is `importedclinicdisp`.

**Slow Cells.Clear Code**

```
Sub ReconcileCCs()

Dim importedclinicdisp As Worksheet
Dim importedcc As Worksheet
Dim importedophcc As Worksheet

Set importedclinicdisp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet7.Name) 'Deposit Recon Imported CLINIC DISP tab
Set importedcc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet8.Name) 'Deposit Recon Imported CREDIT CARD tab
Set importedophcc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet13.Name) 'Deposit Recon Imported OPH CC Tab

importedclinicdisp.Columns.Hidden = False

'Clear existing data
importedclinicdisp.Cells.Clear
importedcc.Cells.Clear
importedophcc.Cells.Clear
```

**Slow import code**

```
Sub ListFiles(fld As Object)

    Dim ddis As Workbook
    Dim ddis_depositdist As Worksheet
    Dim ddis_cctab As Worksheet
    Dim importedclinicdisp As Worksheet
    Dim importedcc As Worksheet
    Dim importedophcc As Worksheet

    Dim ddis_depositdistLastRow As Long
    Dim deposit_recon_cdLastRow As Long
    Dim deposit_recon_ccLastRow As Long
    Dim deposit_recon_cdNewLastRow As Long
    Dim ddis_cctabLastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Dim fl As Object 'File

    Set importedclinicdisp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet7.Name) 'Deposit Recon Imported CLINIC DISP tab
    Set importedcc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet8.Name) 'Deposit Recon Imported CREDIT CARD tab
    Set importedophcc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet13.Name) 'Deposit Recon Imported OPH CC Tab

    For Each fl In fld.Files
            Debug.Print fld.Path & "\" & fl.Name

                    On Error GoTo WorkbookOpenFail
                    Workbooks.Open (fl.Path)
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    Set ddis = Workbooks(fl.Name)
                    Set ddis_depositdist = ddis.Worksheets("CLINC DISP")
                    Set ddis_cctab = ddis.Worksheets("CREDIT CARDS")

                    '1.1 Import CLINIC DISP sheet of DDIS
                    'Find the last row of deposit recon cc tab
                    With importedclinicdisp

                    deposit_recon_cdLastRow = importedclinicdisp.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=importedclinicdisp.Range("A1"), _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row
                    If deposit_recon_cdLastRow < 3 Then deposit_recon_cdLastRow = 3

                    End With

                    'Paste the file name of the DDIS that is being imported from.
                    importedclinicdisp.Range(Cells(deposit_recon_cdLastRow + 1, 1).Address, _
                    Cells(deposit_recon_cdLastRow + 72, 1).Address).Value = fl.Name

                    'Copy the clinic deposit distribution info from DDIS.
                    importedclinicdisp.Range(Cells(deposit_recon_cdLastRow + 1, 2).Address, Cells(deposit_recon_cdLastRow + 72, 27).Address).Value = ddis_depositdist.Range("A3:Z74").Value

                    '1.1.1 Import Ophthalmology information
                    With importedophcc
                        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(importedophcc.Cells) <> 0 Then
                            LastRow = 1 + importedophcc.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=importedophcc.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
                            Else: LastRow = 3
                        End If
                    End With

                    ddis_depositdist.Range("A76:Z94").UnMerge
                    importedophcc.Range(importedophcc.Cells(LastRow, 2), importedophcc.Cells(LastRow + 18, "Z")).Value = ddis_depositdist.Range("A76:Z94").Value
                    importedophcc.Range(importedophcc.Cells(LastRow, 1), importedophcc.Cells(LastRow + 18, 1)).Value = ddis_depositdist.Range("I1").Value



                    '1.2 Import CREDIT CARDS sheet of DDIS
                    'Find the last row on the credit cards import tab of Deposit Recon
                    With importedcc
                        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(importedcc.Cells) <> 0 Then
                            deposit_recon_ccLastRow = importedcc.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=importedcc.Range("A1"), _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row
                        Else
                            deposit_recon_ccLastRow = 2
                        End If
                    End With

                    'Find the last row on the CREDIT CARDS tab of DDIS
                    With ddis_cctab
                        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ddis_cctab.Cells) <> 0 Then
                            ddis_cctabLastRow = ddis_cctab.Cells.Columns(1).Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=ddis_cctab.Range("A1"), _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row
                        Else
                            deposit_recon_ccLastRow = 2
                        End If
                    End With

                    'Write the DDIS file imported from in the left-most column.
                    importedcc.Range(Cells(deposit_recon_ccLastRow + 1, 1).Address, _
                    Cells(deposit_recon_ccLastRow + ddis_cctabLastRow - 4, 1).Address).Value = fl.Name

                    'Copy the CREDIT CARDS tab info from DDIS.
                    importedcc.Range(Cells(deposit_recon_ccLastRow + 1, 2).Address, Cells(deposit_recon_ccLastRow + ddis_cctabLastRow - 4, 8).Address).Value = ddis_cctab.Range(Cells(5, 1).Address, Cells(ddis_cctabLastRow, 8).Address).Value



                    'End file handling code

                    Workbooks(fl.Name).Close SaveChanges:=False

NextWorkbook:
    Next
Exit Sub

WorkbookOpenFail:

    MsgBox (fl.Name & " could not be opened. The import will proceed to the next workbook.")
    Resume NextWorkbook

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried using `.cells.delete`

Comment: are objects being imported from the other workbook? use `home tab > find select > goto special > objects` to identify any objects on page. maybe these would slow down the code.

Comment: @rohrl77 Good ideas. Tried `.Cells.Delete` , it took even longer than `.Cells.Clear`. No objects identified with GoTo Special > Objects either.

Comment: Have you created a new sheet from scratch and run the macro on that? At least for testing purposes.

Comment: What if you change `.value` to `.value2`. I know this is supposed to be a bit faster (it ignores formatting on dates and currencies so don't do it if you need those). this might speed up the import slightly, but I don't think if would have any affect on the deleting.

Comment: Yet another version would be `.clearcontents`

Comment: It could be corrupt, save a version as a web file and look at the size of the pages created, especially the suspect one.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Made a new sheet and the former speed returned.

Comment: @rohrl77 Good tip, but I need date and currency formatting.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I saved the whole spreadsheet as .htm and the file size for the offending sheet didn't appear to be significantly bigger than the other sheets. I also exported the offending an a new sheet individually as .htm, same story. Maybe from here I just research preventing corrupt worksheets? If it happens again I don't mind deleting and making a new sheet, but I want to spin this off to some folks who don't know VBA.

Comment: How long does it take to process all the workbooks?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

### Class RangeDataLoader

```
Option Explicit
Private Const MaxRows As Long = 10000
Private DataArray As Variant
Public DestinationColumn As Range
Private row As Long

Sub AddArray(SourceArray As Variant, Optional RepeatArray As Long = 1)
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim w As Long, x As Long, y As Long

    For w = 1 To RepeatArray
        For x = 1 To UBound(SourceArray, 1)
            If row = 0 Then ReDim DataArray(1 To MaxRows, 1 To UBound(SourceArray, 2))
            row = row + 1
            For y = 1 To UBound(SourceArray, 2)
                DataArray(row, y) = SourceArray(x, y)
            Next
            If row = MaxRows Then TransferData
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub TransferData()
    Dim Target As Range
    If IsEmpty(DataArray) Then Exit Sub
    With DestinationColumn
        Set Target = .Columns(1).Rows(.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Target.Resize(row, UBound(DataArray, 2)) = DataArray
    End With
    row = 0
End Sub
```

### Process the files in a folder

```
Sub LoadData(fld As Object)
    EventsTimer "Process Files"
    Dim temp(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim DataLoaders(4) As RangeDataLoader

    Set DataLoaders(0) = New RangeDataLoader: Set DataLoaders(0).DestinationColumn = Sheet7.Columns("B")    'DISP.Range("A3:Z74")
    Set DataLoaders(1) = New RangeDataLoader: Set DataLoaders(1).DestinationColumn = Sheet13.Columns("A")    'DISP.Range("I1")
    Set DataLoaders(2) = New RangeDataLoader: Set DataLoaders(2).DestinationColumn = Sheet13.Columns("B")    'DISP.Range("A76:Z94")
    Set DataLoaders(3) = New RangeDataLoader: Set DataLoaders(3).DestinationColumn = Sheet8.Columns("A")    'FileName
    Set DataLoaders(4) = New RangeDataLoader: Set DataLoaders(4).DestinationColumn = Sheet8.Columns("B")    'CC.Range("A5", "H" & rwCC).Value

    For Each oFile In fld.Files

        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=oFile.Path, ReadOnly:=True)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print oFile.Path
        Else
            With wb.Worksheets("CLINC DISP")
                temp(1, 1) = .Range("I1").Value2
                DataLoaders(0).AddArray .Range("A3:Z74").Value2
                DataLoaders(1).AddArray temp, 19
                DataLoaders(2).AddArray .Range("A76:Z94").Value2
            End With

            With wb.Worksheets("CREDIT CARDS")
                With .Range("A5", .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                    temp(1, 1) = oFile.Name
                    DataLoaders(3).AddArray temp, .Rows.Count
                    DataLoaders(4).AddArray .Value2
                End With
            End With
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next
    DataLoaders(0).TransferData
    DataLoaders(1).TransferData
    DataLoaders(2).TransferData
    DataLoaders(3).TransferData
    DataLoaders(4).TransferData
    EventsTimer "Process Files"
End Sub
```

### Event Timer

```
Static Sub EventsTimer(Optional EventName As String)
    Dim dict As Object
    If dict Is Nothing Then Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If dict.Exists(EventName) Then
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print String(10, "-"), String(10, "-")
        Debug.Print EventName
        Debug.Print ; "Start Time:"; ; Now - dict(EventName)
        Debug.Print ; "End Time:"; ; Now
        Debug.Print ; "Duration:"; ; Timer - dict(EventName) & " Seconds"
        Debug.Print String(10, "-"); String(10, "-"); String(10, "-")
        dict.Remove EventName
    Else
        dict.Add EventName, CDbl(Timer)
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = dict.Count = 0
        .EnableEvents = dict.Count = 0
        .DisplayAlerts = dict.Count = 0
        .Calculation = IIf(dict.Count = 0, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .CutCopyMode = dict.Count = 0
        .DisplayStatusBar = dict.Count = 0
    End With

End Sub
```